# Binary rejection on apple store while running iOS 10.0.2 connected to an IPv6 network

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have uploaded my app related to chat to apple store. I am using iOS 9.3. After upload, I got a rejection message:

Your app crashes on iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.0.2 connected to an IPv6 network when we:

Specifically, we found that the app crashes after sending messages.

- Offline
- On Wi-Fi

Please suggest me what may i do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you use UIWebView in code?

Comment: No sir. I didn't.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma are you check the offline condition ?

Comment: Yes, I checked, but it is not crashing. It just working fine. I also want to tell you that i am using iOS 9.3

Comment: Please provide information on the frameworks you use.

Comment: I used corelocation, avfoundation, avkit, mediaplayer, quartzcore, coregraphics, foundation, uikit frameworks.

Comment: Hello again , My app crash when i select image or video offline. But working fine online.

Comment: Are you using some hard code URL in your App, make sure they are all support IPV6, you can test on this website: http://ready.chair6.net/

Answer (score 0):

I have already gone through same problem. I have Found several solutions. Any of this might be working for you.

1) It is related to Image issue in iPad check out this [Link](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/64993-app-rejectedcrashing-on-ipv6-possible-solution/).

2) `UIWebview` Deprecated in iOS 10 so check for this. You can find Refrence [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522607/crash-when-use-uiwebview-on-ipad-and-iphone-running-ios-10-0-on-wi-fi-connected)

**In my case first solution work for me.**